# weblogic 12c: server out file is not getting updated, it is buffering the out file even though if I set Log file Buffer to 0

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

weblogic 12c: server out file is not getting updated, it is buffering the out file even though if I set Log file Buffer to 0.

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: In which location are you looking for the stdout file ? you can use the following flags to create it in a directory of your choice.. (make sure the user running weblogic has write access to this directory) -Dweblogic.Stdout=/var/log/weblogic/wlsServer2.out -Dweblogic.Stderr=/var/log/weblogic/wlsServer2_err.out'

Comment: I use custom location. It do have write access. The problem is that the out file is writing only when a buffer of 8kb is reached. Instead of this buffering, I want to write this out file without any buffering.

Comment: Are you setting buffering for the standard output file or for the weblogic server log file ? You question and answers are a bit confused.

Comment: I didn't added any buffering to the standard output. But my issue is that this standard output file is appending only when it reaches ~8kb of text.

Comment: ah yes I have noticed weblogic buffer content before flushing to log file.. you have set low buffer size as I can see.. there could potentially be a bug in the version you are using.  In production environments this is not seen as an issue.